# Cannot build a scala program "sbt package" failed with Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, sbt

I created the following test Scala program using IntelliJ (sbt project).

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import java.sql._

object ConnTest extends App {
  val conf = new SparkConf()
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf.setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[*]"))
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
  val jdbcSqlConn = "jdbc:sqlserver://...;databaseName=...;user=...;password=...;"
  val jdbcDf = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
    "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
    "dbtable" -> "table1"
  )).load()
  jdbcDf.show(10)

  sc.stop()
}
```

However, `sbt package` got the following error. I've downloaded MS Sql server driver (`C:\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar`) from Microsoft website. How to set the jar reference in the sbt project?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.(JDBCOptions.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.(JDBCOptions.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
        at ConnTest$.delayedEndpoint$ConnTest$1(main.scala:14)
        at ConnTest$delayedInit$body.apply(main.scala:6)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at ConnTest$.main(main.scala:6)
        at ConnTest.main(main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: put the jar in lib folder

Comment: There is no folder with name `lib` in my project folder tree? There is a root folder `External Libraries` with two subfolders `< 1.8 >` and `scala-sdk-2.12.1`.

Comment: `External Libraries` is intellij term, create a folder `lib` via command line or through intellij and then copy the jar you want.

Comment: I've been dealing with Spark and Scala lately and would also like to mention that Spark only supports Scala up to 2.11. So there may be issues if you're trying to use 2.12 (not guaranteed, but possible)

Answer (score 1):

[put any external jars in `lib` folder](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html), create `lib` if does not exist(`mkdir -p lib`).

```
build.sbt
lib/
  sqljdbc42.jar
project/
src/
```

Another way could be publishing the jar to your ivy repo (`~/.ivy`)

Then you can simply go to `sbt console` and verify that the jar is loaded.

Comment: I started spark by `spark-shell --driver-class-path C:\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar`. Do I still need to specify `--driver-class-path` after I rebuilt the program after the lib\....jar is added?

Comment: BTW, the scala code can be built after added the lib\...jar file. However, `spark-submit.cmd --class ConnTest --master local[4] .\target\scala-2.11\mpa_2.11-1.0.jar` still get the same error?

Comment: Getting the same error even though the jar is in my lib. Any ideas?